# Why can't I use a variable to extract a specific value from an array (or arraylist), for example check the following code

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

```
public static void main(){

int num = 0;                                                                      
      int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};   
      System.out.println(numbers(num));
      //so I expect 1 as the result, but get an error instead    

}
```

Comment: You can find alot of informations and examples about arrays here : http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/99/arrays

Answer (score 7):

Use square brackets

```
System.out.println(numbers[num]);
```

Comment: I have no idea who downvoted you. But that person is not very clever.

Comment: Thnks for the help

Answer (score 5):

```
int num = 0;
int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
System.out.println(numbers[num]);
```

you access an array by using a square bracket i.e [] and not ()

Comment: Thanks, and sorry XD